# Canada FSALDU 6-digit Postal Code Data Providers

Tags: data, accuracy, postal-code

I have been looking into finding point data for the Canadian 6-digit postal code (FSALDU). I have come up with 3 sources so far, 2 being far more expensive than the other. After speaking with the sales reps they all seem to be only offering me just the data. Does anyone know what is a causing the large difference in price? Are the more expensive ones more accurate or something?

Cheapest (by far)
[Statistics Canada](http://www5.statcan.gc.ca/bsolc/olc-cel/olc-cel?lang=eng&catno=92-154-X)

Most Expensive
[DMTI Spatial](http://offers.dmtispatial.com/rs/dmtispatial/images/CanMap-PostalCodeSuite-Brochure-web.pdf) , www.maponics.com/products/gis-map-data/canadian-postal-codes-database/overview

Answer (score 2):

The price difference is probably due private vs public nature of the providers. I have never had an accuracy issues using government provided spatial data - census tracts etc. If price is one of your main concerns, you may wish to look into the free Canadian Postal Code centroids at http://geocoder.ca/ That being said, the red *'You haven't made it until you get sued'* warning at the top of the free download page page may give you pause before using the data.

Answer (score -1):

I can't access both the providers that OP mentioned above. However with my own research, found several commercial providers that are quite promising. Data from IGEOCODE seems to be the most complete and competitive in pricing. I can't compare the price with the 2 providers that OP mentioned, so can't really tell if it this is cheaper than those. For reference, anyone need the Canada postal code database (down to street level), you can take a look at IGEOCODE offering at https://www.igeocode.com/products/capostalcodes/gold. They also have a demo site at https://www.igeocode.com/products/capostalcodes/demo.

Answer (score -1):

***Disclaimer I am a developer for https://boundaries-io.com***

You can query by postal FSA or LDU(6 digits code) and obtain the GeoJson Polygon.

There are no 'official polygons' for LDU codes , so these companies  generate them using algorithms.

to search for a 6 digit Canada point **K1A 0B1**

Results:

Example query:
`.../rest/v1/public/boundary/ca/ldu?postal-ldu=k1a0b1`
[image]